# How to Bind 'Double Shift' KeyPress in Emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Is there any way exist to bind `double shift` keypress to a specific method like `find-grep`?

Comment: What does `double shift` mean, in terms of keyboard keys? Or are you talking about a double-click of a mouse button?

Comment: @Drew , I mean pressing `shift` key twice.

Comment: The Shift key is a modifier key, at least by default. It has an effect only by pressing it while another key is hit.

Comment: @Drew, then it's impossible in emacs? because in `pycharm` it works. I think I've seen in vim too.

Comment: It's not impossible, but by default Shift is a modifier key. Perhaps someone here can tell you how to make it into an ordinary key. (I won't ask why you want this. ;-))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Emacs SE website